# Problem getting document from firestore (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a problem in my code and wanted to see if someone could help me. I am trying to get a document from the firestore when the user presses a button, the problem I have is that I get the document but when I try to pass it to the sheet I get an error.

As you can see in the code, I have a print in the button, when the action is done if the name of the user is printed, what I need is to pass the userDoc to the sheet to be able to put the User in the Profile View.

Error:

[image]

Code:

```
  Button(action: {

                                let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(viewModel.post.ownerUid)

                                    docRef.getDocument { snapshot, _ in
                                        guard let userDoc = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
                                        
                                        print("\(userDoc.username)")
                                       self.showProfilePost.toggle()
                                    }

                            }, label: {

                                Text("by  \(viewModel.post.ownerUsername)")
                                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                .opacity(0.9)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .padding(.leading)
                            })
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showProfilePost, content: {
                                ProfileView(user: userDoc)
                            })
```

Firestore:
Here you can see that the Users collection has several users, with my function I get one of these and print it in the console. What I need is for that user to be able to pass it to my profileView.

[image]

User struct:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
let username: String
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error is showing you, you don't have access to `userDoc` outside of the `Button`'s `action` closure because `userDoc` is defined *inside* that closure. To fix the issue, you must have a way to store it *outside* of the closure. The most barebones way to accomplish this would be to use a `@State` variable to hold `userDoc`:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: UUID
    let username: String
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var userDoc : User? = nil
    
    var body : some View {
        Button(action: {
            userDoc = User(id: UUID(), username: "Username") //set userDoc inside of your Firebase call
        }) {
            Text("Press me")
        }
        .sheet(item: $userDoc) { userDoc in
            ProfileView(user: userDoc)
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileView : View {
    var user : User
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("User view")
    }
}
```

Normally, I prefer to keep async code in a view model, which only looks *slightly* different:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userDoc : User?
    
    func fetchUser() {
        //Firebase code here
        userDoc = User(id: UUID(), username: "Username")
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body : some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.fetchUser()
        }) {
            Text("Press me")
        }
        .sheet(item: $viewModel.userDoc) { userDoc in
            ProfileView(user: userDoc)
        }
    }
}
```